# get user birthday facebook connect

Tags: facebook

I make facebook application

How can I get user birthday ?

This is my code , I can get only user email

```
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '750206668427291',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
      FB.login(function(response) {     if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));});} else {
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');  },{  scope: 'user_birthday,email,user_photos'});

    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to do this with a user who does not have a role in the App. Most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before they can be used for everyone else. The `email` permission is approved by default, but you have to go through the review process with `user_birthday`. You can read everything about the review process in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Short version: Before approval, `user_birthday` will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Comment: if I want to publish the results of a quiz , I would need an access token

Comment: not sure what you want to tell me with that, this thread is about getting the user birthday, not publishing something...that´s a completely different topic...

Comment: Yes I know that I published something that´s a completely different topic but I did not want to create another topic